# Different header for odd and even pages with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, book-design

We are making a book with the document class `book`. We use the `fancyhdr` package to customize the headings. We want the book title on LE and the chapter name on RO. We tried

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
       \markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
        \markright{\thesection\ #1}}
%\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[LE]{This is book title}
\fancyhead[RO]{\emph{\thechapter}}
```

but now the title is overlapping with the chapter name in the header in odd pages.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 14):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% The paper headers
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\small\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\small IEEE Transactions on Vehicular Technology,~Vol.~7, No.~7, Oct~2011}% odd page header and number to right top
\fancyhead[RE]{\small ElBadawy H., \textit{Performability Modeling}}%Even page header and number at left top
\fancyfoot[L,R,C]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% disable the underline of the header part
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look over [here,](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout) section "Selectors". That should let you do something just for odd or even pages.

Comment: This link helped me fix the issue http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1357

Comment: @j4v4m4n: You should put this down as an answer and accept it, since [it's OK to answer your own questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).